# What is the python script for sending email through yandex account?

Tags: python-3.x, django, email, yandex

```
import smtplib
server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.yandex.com',465)
server.starttls()
server.login('admin@cbitcse.cf','XXXXX')
message='hurray'
server.sendmail('admin@cbitcse.cf','xyz@gmail.com',message)
server.quit()
print('E-mail successfully sent!')
```

**Note**: Here .cf is a free domain.I have got a free domain-based email address(*admin@cbitcse.ml*) with yandex.

Why is this code not working? Any configuration settings needs to changed in yandex account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Yandex mail service, STARTTLS is also not working for me. Replace this one

```
server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.yandex.com',465)
server.starttls()
```

with

```
server=smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.yandex.com',465)
```